# How can i update excisting word document using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, Now trying to develop a word document(.docx), for that i need to substitute some heading in some pages. How can i append some text to exsiting word using python with out the replacement method ?

Comment: Do you mean "Microsoft Word"? For an answer the document format docx/doc might be important.

Comment: yes, i am trying to update .docx file

Comment: Might want to look into the [python-docx](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module.

Comment: Thanks for comments, I already cheked that document. Actualy am trying to append some text to exsisting word document. There i couldn't find any way to do the same.